# RecyclerView with fixed column and header, plus scrollable footer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to find a way to implement a standing table for a sports app (like NBA Game Time standings), with a fixed header, fixed first column and a footer. I searched a bit on how to get it, but the best shot was this project (https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders) but it uses its own view instead of Recycler of GridView. Do anyone knows something like this or knows how I can start with it (Adapter or LayoutManager)?

**Edit** (adding images)

[image: initial state]

[image: scrolled state showing footer]

Comment: While it's possible, it's not trivial. I need a solution like that, and if I ever get to build one with a RecyclerView, I'll open source it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After testing and searching a lot, I implemented by my own, combining a `ListView` with inner `HorizontalScrollView`s.

First, I extended `HorizontalScrollView` to report me the scroll event, adding a listener:

```
public class MyHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

    private OnScrollListener listener;

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (listener != null) listener.onScroll(this, l, t);
    }

    public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnScrollListener {
        void onScroll(HorizontalScrollView view, int x, int y);
    }       
}
```

Then, I created my layout with a `LinearLayout`, containing my header and a `ListView` for my `Activity` (or `Fragment`, if it's your need).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Each item of my list is a `LinearLayout`, with a `TextView` (the fixed column) and a `HorizontalScrollView`. The layout of both header and lines are the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <net.rafaeltoledo.example.MyHorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- Childs, or columns -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </net.rafaeltoledo.example.MyHorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The trick is to scroll all With a help of a `EventBus` (I used the [GreenRobot's](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) one) to fire the horizontal scroll event and move all scrollers as one. My event object contains the same data from the listener class (maybe I can use the listener object itself?)

```
public static class Event {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private final HorizontalScrollView view;

    public Event(HorizontalScrollView view, int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.view = view;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public HorizontalScrollView getView() {
        return view;
    }
}
```

The list adapter class receives a listener to set in the `HorizontalScrollView` of each item.

```
public static class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context context;
    private MyHorizontalScrollView.OnScrollListener listener;

    public Adapter(Context context, MyHorizontalScrollView.OnScrollListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 30;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return new Object();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
            MyHorizontalScrollView scroll = (MyHorizontalScrollView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scroll);
            scroll.setOnScrollListener(listener);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Before continue, I registered `MyHorizontalScrollView` to EventBus, adding `EventBus.getDefault().register(this)` to each version of constructor, and added the receiver method to it:

```
public void onEventMainThread(MainActivity.Event event) {
    if (!event.getView().equals(this)) scrollTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
}
```

that will scroll to the received position, if was not itself that fired the scroll event.

And finally, I setted up everything in the `onCreate()` method of my `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    MyHorizontalScrollView.OnScrollListener listener = new MyHorizontalScrollView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScroll(HorizontalScrollView view, int x, int y) {
            Log.d("Scroll Event", String.format("Fired! %d %d", x, y));
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new Event(view, x, y));
        }
    };

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.header);
    header.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    header.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    ((MyHorizontalScrollView) header.findViewById(R.id.scroll)).setOnScrollListener(listener);

    listView.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, listener));
    listView.addFooterView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, listView, false));
}
```

(Please ignore some weird coloring, it's for better viewing what's happening).

And ta-daa, here is the desired result!

[image: final result]

Comment: your solution is looking good... can i have the full source for the same  on lankevijayavarma@gmail.com. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a layout like that like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        ... />

    <com.example.TableHeaderView 
        ... />

    <RecyclerView 
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Only the RecyclerView will scroll, leaving your title text view and table header at the top of the screen.

Comment: The tricky part is that both header and first colum should scroll alongside the content. eg: if I scroll horizontally, the header should scroll too to keep the column label fitting the alignment. Same for the vertical scroll.

Answer (score 1):

From your images I would suggest considering using a library such as [StickyGridHeaders](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders). It extends `GridView` and can have custom 'header' views.

Alternatives are [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) or [HeaderListView](http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/) but focus more on the `ListView`

**Edit:**

On further investigation, the example provided [in this tutorial](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/08/android-scroll-table-fixed-header-column.html) seems to match your requirements

Comment: Yes, I played with it a bit (and SuperSLIM too, the version of the library for RecyclerViews), but I didn't found a way to keep not only the header, but the first column sticked with this libraries. As I posted, the best solution that I found was **TableFixHeaders**, but it is not a RecyclerView or GridView, is a full custom view, so it don't allow me to do so much customization with it.

Comment: Do you mean the first row? Stil not 110% sure what you want to scroll and what not too

Comment: When I scroll horizontally, the first column (with the team names) must be keep (like a sticky column)