# How to slide the recyclerview to the upper left and lower right corners, not just swipe up or down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

Hello, the above picture I through recyclerview to complete, I want to achieve is that when the "recyclerview content" to slide up, leftHeader can slide up, when the "recyclerview content" to slide to the left and right Time, topHeader can slide around, and, When the "recyclerview content" to the upper left corner or the lower right corner of the slide, leftHeader and topHeader can also be sliding at the same time.

I think this is an interesting and challenging problem, and my idea is now by rewriting "recyclerview LayoutManager" or "ViewDragHelper" to achieve, because "RecyclerView LayoutManager" under normal circumstances can not slide to the upper left corner, but has not yet achieved
So ask the idea of everyone, welcome Tucao

Comment: this might be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/29421178/1548824

Comment: Thank you very much Akhilesh Patil's answer, and now my needs are such as: first use a method to achieve "recyclerview content" can move to the upper left corner of 45 degrees, when the "recyclerview content" to the upper left corner of the 45 degrees, "leftHeader" Move up, and at the same time, "topHeader" moves to the left, they are done at the same time